# Communication between Siblings in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, publish-subscribe, flux

Let us consider a scenario described below

Parent Component contains two child components

1. Child Component 1 which contains 3 components

   a. A table

   b. An inline table editing row wherein the user can enter new values 
      and save them by making a rest call which updates the table.

   c. Pagination

The state of the Child Component 1 becomes

```
a. currentPage

b. table data

c. totalPages
```

2. Child Component 2 also contains 5 components

   a. A table

   b. Dropdown 1 whose options are fetched from rest api

   c. Dropdown 2 whose options are fetched from rest api

   d. Dropdown 3 whose options are fetched from rest api

   e. Pagination

   f. Change in selection of Dropdown 1 triggers change in Dropdown 2 
       and Dropdown 3 i.e they make rest call based on selected value in 
       Dropdown 1.

   g. Change in selection of Dropdown 2 triggers change in Dropdown 3 
       i.e it makes rest call based on selected value in Dropdown 2.

The state of the Child Component 2 becomes

```
a. currentPage

b. table data

c. totalPages

d. selectedOptionForDropdown1

e. selectedOptionForDropdown2

f. selectedOptionForDropdown3
```

However when the user interacts with the Child Component 1 by adding new row it triggers a change in Child Component 2 such that all the Drop-downs need to fetch updated list as a new row was added in Child Component 1.

How will the Child Component 1 interact with Child Component 2. Options are

1. PubSub
2. Flux
3. Ref in react
4. Via Parent Component

Which is a better approach?

Also does moving the state of Child Component 1 and Child Component 2 into parent component makes sense or using a redux store will be a better option?

Comment: For the last question, there is no a "better" option. If your app will get bigger and you will need those kind of data for other components Redux would be a good option. But for your situation as you guess lifting the state up to the parent component solves your problem.

Comment: So say if I move the states out of Child Components into Parent, in a scenario where the pagination in child component 2 updates the state in parent resulting into a rest call to fetch new data for table in Child Component 2 would also trigger a re-render for Child Component 1 which seems unnecessary as the state for Child Component 1 has not really changed.

Comment: This is why I said there is not a better option. Rerendering is not so expensive if there aren't lots and lots of components like those childs. Do not bother with rerendering so much. Also, if you really want to stop rerendering, you can use PureComponent. Again, if there will be cases like that in the other parts of your app, go with Redux or a similar approach. By the way I'm not an experienced developer but there aren't so many options to make your components communicate: either lifting the state up or use a global state.